# Can any CSS stylesheet rules be applied to head, link, meta, or style tags?

Tags: css, hyperlink, styles, meta, head

I'm trying to create a CSS parser for an application at work. It seems to me that in addition to the script tag, css stylesheet rules cannot be applied to the html tags mentioned in the title. For example, the following is pointless:

```
link[href="http://www.thiswebsite.com"] {display:none;}
```

as would these be pointless:

```
meta {color:red;}
meta[content="text/css"] {width:100%;}
```

Are there any rules one can apply in a stylesheet that would somehow alter or select for the `head`, `link`, `style`, or `meta` tags for something purposeful? (besides simply selecting those tags and applying irrelevant rules)

Comment: `head, title { display:block; }` would show the page title on the page. Is that the sort of thing you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/qyw48cdg/

Comment: @TomKentell - http://alohci.net/static/stylehead.htm

Comment: @Alohci...no I was wondering if there is a css rule you could apply to eg <head> that would actually be usable in an application. eg if 2 meta tags and 1 is content="text/css" do not apply this meta tag. I don't think there is any css that does anything like this, which makes using these tags in stylesheet pointless

Comment: @Alohci my apologies! You are totally correct haha. Weird, never seen that before!

Comment: @Alohci...ok, I will factor in this type of use case. Thanks for the info...why don't you submit that in answer form?